# C++ Get 64bit Process Base Address

Tags: c++, windows, memory, 64-bit, radix

I have been trying to get the base address of a 64bit process. (Win 10)

I looked up everywhere and tried all of the codes was provided but unfortunately doesn't work any of them.

One of my tries:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

uintptr_t GetModuleBaseAddress(DWORD procId, const wchar_t* modName)
{
    uintptr_t modBaseAddr = 0;
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, procId);
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MODULEENTRY32 modEntry;
        modEntry.dwSize = sizeof(modEntry);
        if (Module32First(hSnap, &modEntry))
        {
            do
            {
                if (!_wcsicmp(modEntry.szModule, modName))
                {
                    modBaseAddr = (uintptr_t)modEntry.modBaseAddr;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnap, &modEntry));
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return modBaseAddr;
}

int main()
{
    DWORD64 Base = GetModuleBaseAddress((DWORD)27976, L"Calculator.exe");
    printf("0x%x", Base);
}
```

The code always gives 0 (if it doesn't have an error) as the base address.

Comment: The code tests all the Win32 API calls for success, but does not output a message if they fail.  For each API call if it fails output the result of GetLastError() (if appropriate) and the name of the failing API call. Note that calling GetLastError() __must__ be done immediately after detecting an API call failure to prevent it's value being overwritten.

Comment: @RichardCritten Ok. I added GetLastError() and it gives 299 error code which means: `299 (0x12B)

Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.`

Comment: From which API call ?

Comment: What is `sizeof(uintptr_t)`? To be able to read 64-bit base addresses, you need to have a 64-bit `uintptr_t`.

Comment: process have not any *base address*. you mean *exe* base address. for get it - not need read information of exe/dlls loaded to process. need read value of `PEB::ImageBaseAddress` and your process need be native, not wow64

Comment: @RbMm Can you help me out with PEB? I don't know how to use it. A sample code would be useful.

Comment: really code is very small - https://pastebin.com/7wTK3b87